# How to add thumb field to Facebook video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**

> please i really need solution for that problem.

**

```
 dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
                            {
                                ContentType = string.Format("video/{0}", VideoExtension.Split('.')[1]),
                                FileName = VideoName
                            }
                            .SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        parameters.title = VideoTitle;
        parameters.description = VideoTitle;           
        parameters.universal_video_id = new Guid();
        parameters.thumb = coverPath;
        parameters.published = false;
        parameters.unpublished_content_type = "DRAFT";
        dynamic uploadresult = fb.Post("/367728493684998/videos", parameters);
```

above code works fine if i comment line `parameters.thumb = coverPath;`

> coverPath is image path.
>   when post run with this field it return error 
>   (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Invalid image format. It should be an image file data.

What is correct image format facebook api waiting for ?

Comment: The actual binary image data, not a path ...

Comment: very good ,but imporatnt question here how can i get binary image data ? i try to convert image to bytes but i not woked also.

Comment: hi, i still need solution for that !